# .Net Process keep command window open

Tags: .net, command-line

right now I am working on a tool that does a lot of work via the `Process` object through the command line. So there are times when I want the command window to not show up and times when I want it to stay open so that the user can see what happened, possibly respond with the appropriate input.

```
 Dim pro As New Process
        pro.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path
        pro.StartInfo.Arguments = command
        pro.StartInfo.FileName = "hg"

        pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        If command.Contains("-q") Then
            pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            pro.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        End If

        pro.Start()

        pro.WaitForExit()

        Return pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
```

The flag that I am checking in the `command` is for a `-q` if it doesn't contain this I would like to show the command prompt to the user and wait for them to close it.

Is this possible and if so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If command.Contains("-q") Then
....
Else
Shell("cmd /k" & Command, 1, True)
End If
```

Comment: Shell doesn't have a valid method like that did you miss something.

Comment: Wierd.  The following code will keep the command line open.
        Dim Command As String
        Command = "ipconfig /all"
        Shell("cmd /k" & Command, 1, True)
But Shell("cmd /c" & Command, 1, True) will close it.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xca6kdd(v=VS.71).aspx
I'm using 3.5 and don't have to add any special imports statement or references to get it to work.